# How can I create multiple checkbox and get the answered ones?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to get checkbox coming from entities.

For example. A have a user with roles. An admin choose a user and give them multiple roles.

I want to create a form, add some checkbox (all the roles, which are saved in the role entity, can change in the timeline).

To do this, I can create a list of roles and pass them to the thymeleaf view. With a `th:each` I can create multiple checkboxes.

But my problem is: How can I then get which checkbox has been clicked?

Thanks for helping

EDIT:

Ok, let me give a little example:

The answer object:

```
public class Answer{

private String label;
private boolean isClicked;

//Some getters and setters

}
```

My java controller:

```
List<Anwer> answers = ...
model.addAttribute("answers", answers);
```

Thymleaf view, anything like:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{'/submitAnswer/'}" th:object="${answer}" method="post">
<div th:each="answer : ${answers}">
  <li><input type="checkbox" th:field="*{answer}" th:value="${answer.label}" /></li>
</div>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>
```

Comment: give each one a unique name, such as the role name.

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't very clear, but the question is more how to get back the list of objects I have sent? Which one has been clicked?